# Split String Mathematical Operators Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I want to split basic mathematical operators from a formula string and get operands, I am using the following regex:

```
(/[+,-,*,/]/g)
```

It is working fine with `+` , `/` and `*` but not with `-`.

**Sample input 1:** `"a+b".split(/[+,-,*,/]/g)` .
**Sample output 1:** ["a","b"] //Works fine

**Sample input 2:** `"a-b".split(/[+,-,*,/]/g)` .
**Sample output 2:** `["a-b"] //Not working fine :( should return ["a", "b"], but returns ["a-b"]`

I would love to know what I am missing in my expression.
I have an alternative i.e. iterate the whole string and returns a new array without operators but I want to use regex.

Thanks

Comment: Use `/[+*\/-]/`, remember to always keep the `-` at the start/end of the character class. Putting `-` at the start of the character class works in all regex flavors I know of.

Comment: You don't need `,` between characters within brackets.

Comment: try this "a-b".split(/[+,\-/,*,/]/g)

Comment: @Sameer ***do not use `,` in the character class***. It doesn't enumerate all possibilities, it means  "include `,` in the list of things matched by this character class".